# TypeScript type to extract all values in a nested record

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have:

```ts
interface JaggedRecord {
    [k: string]: string | JaggedRecord;
}

const MyKeys = {
    SubKey1: {
        child1: 'child1',
        child2: 'child2',
    },
    SubKey2: {
        child3: 'child3',
        child4: 'child4',
        SubKey3: {
            child5: 'child5',
        },
    },
    child6: 'child6',
} as const;

// obviously order doesn't matter
type AllValues = 'child1' | 'child2' | 'child3' | 'child4' | 'child5' | 'child6';
```

Now I want to create a `type` which dynamically generates `AllValues`.

Ever the effective rubber duck, Stack Overflow forced me to figure out the answer in order to write the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a bit simplified solution:

```js
const MyKeys = {
  SubKey1: {
    child1: 'child1',
    child2: 'child2',
  },
  SubKey2: {
    child3: 'child3',
    child4: 'child4',
    SubKey3: {
      child5: 'child5',
    },
  },
  child6: 'child6',
} as const;

type All<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? P : All<T[P]>
}[keyof T]

type Result = All<typeof MyKeys> // 'child1' | 'child2' | 'child3' | 'child4' | 'child5' | 'child6';
```

Comment: Ah, right, I was having trouble with doing that early on, and then once I got it, I forgot to fix it.

Comment: When you return `P` you actually return the key of the nested object not the value. Returning `T[P]` fix that: `type All<T extends Record<string, any>> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? T[P] : All<T[P]>; }[keyof T];`

Answer (score 2):

The trick, of course, turned out to be abstraction that made it easier to reason about what I was retrieving.

```ts
type JaggedRecordKeys<T extends JaggedRecord> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends JaggedRecord ? [K, T[K]] : never;
}[keyof T];

type ExtractAllValues<T extends JaggedRecord> = 
    | { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? T[K] : never }[keyof T] & string
    | { [K in JaggedRecordKeys<T>[0]]: ExtractAllValues<Extract<JaggedRecordKeys<T>, [K, any]>[1]>; }[JaggedRecordKeys<T>[0]];

type AllValues = ExtractAllValues<typeof MyKeys>;
```

First we create a type (`JaggedRecordKeys`) that takes the keys of `T` whose value is not a `string`, then extracts a union of tuples of that key and that key's value.

Then, we make `ExtractAllValues` return all the keys of `T` whose value is a string unioned with the recursive call of every extracted value of `T`'s keys whose value is a `JaggedRecord`, and dereference that recursive call's return value.

I suspect I could make `JaggedRecord` generic to allow any type of child, but when I tried it, `ExtractAllValues` said it had a circular reference.  Since my use-case is specifically for strings, I left it as-is.